# Java file a progress bar

Tags: java, progress-bar, zip, jprogressbar

I'm new to Java.
I want to write a program that makes arcive of file
and i want to use progress bar to show progress of zipping
There is my code, but it duosen't work
shows only 100% when work is done.

```
        getContentPane().add(progressBar);
    progressBar.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(null, null));
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, progressBar, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, messageLabel);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, progressBar, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, messageLabel);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, progressBar, 165, SpringLayout.NORTH, getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, progressBar, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, uploadLocalButton);
    progressBar.setValue(0);
    progressBar.setMaximum(100);
    progressBar.setMinimum(0);
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true); 
...
 public void doZip(String filename,String outFilename) 
 {
     try {
        byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];
        File file = new File(outFilename);
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        File fil = new File(filename); //"Users/you/image.jpg"
        long length= fil.length();
        System.out.println(length);
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fil.getName()));//image.jpg
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        int current=0;
        int len;

        while ((len = in.read(dataBytes)) > 0) 
        { current += len; 
        messageLabel.setText(Integer.toString(current));
        System.out.println(current);
        final double progres=(((double)current/(double)length)*100);
        progressBar.setValue((int)progres);             
            zos.write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.length);
        }

        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();
        in.close();
 }catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Access denied. File or patch not exist or in currently in use.","Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }}
```

Maybe someone knows where is the problem?

---

I call **doZip** by pressing the botton.
I tried this

```
 while ((len = in.read(dataBytes)) > 0) 
        { current += len; 
        zos.write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.length);
        final double progres=(((double)current/(double)length)*100);
        try{
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                progressBar.setValue((int)progres);
                }
            });
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){;}
```

but it also doesent work, only makes process of zip opperation much more longer.

Comment: try wrapping your call to `doZip` in a Thread should to the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are calling `doZip` from somewhere in the AWT thread (e.g. called (in)directly by an action handler as response to a click or something). Therefore the UI is not updated until the action (zipping) is finished, even if you set the progress accordingly in between..

One solution would be to start  `doZip` in a separate thread (in general it is good advice to avoid any costly operation in the AWT thread, but only do basic 'action handling' and trigger long-running operations from there...)